# No top box-shadow?

Tags: css

How could you eliminate the top box-shadow. It would be perfect if CSS had something already built in, but anything rarely is.

Here's a live [example](http://viddir.com).

Scroll down to the bottom of the page to the footer. I want to eliminate the top box-shadow on  the pseudobottom.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
#Background
{
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 30px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 30px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
box-shadow: 0px 1px 30px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Apply this CSS to your #wrapper2

```
#wrapper2{border-radius: 0 0 12px 12px;
          -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 12px 12px;
          -moz-border-radius: 0 0 12px 12px;

}
```

This will solve your design and give the same output that you have desired by including a div with pseudobottom class.

Further, I am also curious to know the purpose of including a div with pseudobottom class. Is it just to resolve the design or it will have the contents too?

Comment: I wish it was that simple. This site is set up in such a way that all the pages inherit the header and the footer. So for it to work site-wide, I got to get this little headache out of the way; in order to avoid several headaches in the future.

Comment: I went to your website and saw your HTML Structure. I suggest that adding a div with pseudobottom class as a patch to solve the structure will only make things patchy and complicated for future. As you can check how your login.php page looks for instance. So making the wrapper div flexible to accomodate any kind of content is the appropriate solution rather than adding hacks or patches.

Comment: It's based on PHPMotion, which was hideous starting off, so I've basically been hacking the whole thing. I revised the code, it's eating the footer on some of the pages. Meh. I essentially used your code, and played around with other factors to make it work. Don't get cocky :)

Answer (score 0):

Used to this add one more **box shadow** for **top** and **bottom** Shadow

****as like this****

```
    .container-wide{
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px #ccc, -1px -1px 1px 1px #ccc;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px #ccc, -1px -1px 1px 1px #ccc;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px #ccc, -1px -1px 1px 1px #ccc;
    }
```

**If  u show only top shadow than apply this css**

```
.container-wide{
-moz-box-shadow: -1px -1px 1px 1px #ccc;
-webkit-box-shadow: -1px -1px 1px 1px #ccc;
box-shadow: -1px -1px 1px 1px #ccc;
}
```